# Get auto generated ID right after flush() Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a `Project` entity and when creating a new project I need to be able to upload files. For this reason I have created `Files` entity which saves the path and projectID. My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve it after creating it. Here is what I am trying to do

```
 $projectService->createProject($project,$user,$isWithoutTerm,self::NO_TERM_DEFAULT_VALUE);
            $filesService = $this->get('app.service.files_service');
            foreach ($managerFiles as $managerFile){
                $fileName = $filesService->uploadFileAndReturnName($managerFile);
                $filesService->createFile($fileName,$project->getId(),$user);
            }
```

Currently my `$project` doesn't have ID which means that I cant create a new file. I heard that I could use $em->retrieve(object), but the actual flushing is not done in the controller. If i try to use it in my `createProject` function and return it for some reason I can't. PHPStorm says that it is a void function. Here is the code in `createProject`

```
        $project->setFromUser($user->getFullName());
        $project->setDepartment($user->getDepartment());
        $project->setIsOver(false);
        $project->setDate(new \DateTime());
        if($isWithoutTerm){
            $project->setTerm(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $noTermDefaultValue));
        }
        $this->entityManager->persist($project);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
```

Is there a way to retrieve the projectID after flushing and being able to use it in my controller?

Comment: After flushing $project->getId() should return the id.  If your IDE is complaining then look at where Project::getId is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a race condition where the $project is not available yet and so the service cannot load it and thus `getId()` fails.

First, create your project entity:

```
//build your $project
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Second, send this $project to your "service"

```
$projectService->createProject($project,$user,$isWithoutTerm,self::NO_TERM_DEFAULT_VALUE);
$filesService = $this->get('app.service.files_service');
foreach ($managerFiles as $managerFile){
    $fileName = $filesService->uploadFileAndReturnName($managerFile);
    $filesService->createFile($fileName,$project->getId(),$user);
}
```

More specifically if you wrap this in a try/catch you can identify exactly what is happening:

```
try {

    $project = new Project();
    //build project
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    //load $projectService..

    $projectService->createProject($project,$user,$isWithoutTerm,self::NO_TERM_DEFAULT_VALUE);
    $filesService = $this->get('app.service.files_service');
    foreach ($managerFiles as $managerFile){
        $fileName = $filesService->uploadFileAndReturnName($managerFile);
        $filesService->createFile($fileName,$project->getId(),$user);
    }

}
catch(\Exception $e) {

    //$e->getMessage() will tell you if you're good to go, or if there
    //is actually an issue

}
```

However, it could also be as simple as PHPStorm not being able to introspect your `getId()` method and thus doesn't understand it. OR `getId()` is not actually returning the id.

Comment: This is nuts. Here is what I have discovered - http://prntscr.com/fpvo7z . Seems like I can actually use $project->getId(), but not inside the foreach. Which is crazy. Creating the project works just fine, but when I try to insert a file with projectID "null" it throws this - An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO files (date, from, filePath, projectID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2017-06-30 07:53:29", "Manager", "..\/..\/..\/web\/files\/", null]:. As you can see only projectID is null and breaks everything

Comment: I have no idea how, but I upgraded my Symfony version  from 3.2 to 3.3 and fixed depricated stuff and it works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the Symfony from 3.2 and 3.3 fixed the issue. I don't think it was due to the version itself, but rather removing depricated stuff and changing a lot of things and something fixed it.